# Add Joliet after burning ISO9660 disc

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, dvd

I made multiple copies of a data disk using the following commands:

```
genisoimage -r -f -o dvd.iso folder/
wodim -eject dvd.iso
wodim -eject dvd.iso
# ...
wodim -eject dvd.iso
```

As far as I can tell, these DVDs contain the ISO9660 filesystem with [Rock Ridge extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge), and not UDF.
`man genisoimage` says:

> `-udf` Include UDF filesystem support in the generated filesystem image.  UDF support is currently in alpha status and for this reason, it is not possible to create UDF-only images.

These DVDs work fine in Linux machines, but in Windows, only the [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) show up, since they are missing the [Joliet filesystem extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system)).
Is it possible to add the Joliet data *after* burning the disks, so that the filenames will show up properly on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you burned them to write once media and not rewriteable media it's unlikely. Depending on the burn settings in rare cases there might be an option. Without really looking into it's likely that Joilet is a compatible format that uses previously unused gaps or extends certain parts of the base format. You can't overwrite those on write once media.

Comment: I was hoping that it was possible to write something *after* the existing data. I'll accept your answer until someone else comes up with a solution.

Comment: The [wiki for wodim](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/wodim/) mentions that it does support multi session burning. I'm not sure whenever you can do that retroactively. Also it might be important whenever the disc was burned session at once or disc at once.

Comment: It was burned with the exact commands shown in my question. The default is `-tao` (Track-At-Once).